# Switch browser in Electron based application

Tags: node.js, macos, safari, electron, chromium

I'd like to develop an Electron based application that provide cross platform UI that is implemented using web-based code (like HTML, Javascript & CSS and Node.js) for the UI rendering part which is interpreted using Chromium engine and displayed from Chromium browser windows.

I was thinking to switch the UI engine to builtin `WebKit` based engine like Safari in order to reduce my application memory footprint under macOS. I believe it should be possible since Safari, like Chromium and any other browser, is also capable of rendering UI from the high level languages mentioned above.

Did anybody have tried it ? Is it possible in practice to choose the UI entine of my application per platform ?

Comment: Vote to reopen: I only see one question being asked here (even before the edit).

Comment: I think Electron is fundamentally tied to chromium, so to swap it out and use a different rendering engine would be quite a major fork. Not sure, though, so it'll be interesting to see if you get other responses.

Comment: @DarrenCook The Needs Focus is often used even when there's technically only one question being asked, but that question lacks focus. As an extreme example, "How can I write an operating system?" is only one question, and it's a perfectly clear question, but it's too unfocused; i.e. an attempt to answer that question would require a substantially more involved answer than is suitable for the SO Q&A format.

Comment: @cigien. Of course I'm biased, but i believe that this question is pretty focused. it mainly asks if there's an option to use another UI engine for electron like the default engine in macOS which is safari/webkit. This will achieve significant result in terms of reducing app memory footprint, as the engine is already there in any macOS arch. The answer should be Yes (and how) or No (with reason).

Comment: @Zohar81 Yes, that's fine. I think this question needs a bit more focus, but I was responding to Darren's comment about a question potentially being unfocused even if it's technically asking only one question.